# Where did the nickname "Poppo" comes from?

Tags: anohana

We know that all of them have a nickname, but I don't understand Poppo's nickname.

- Yadomi **Jinta** = Jintan
- Ho**nma Me**iko = Menma
- **An**jou **Naru**ko = Anaru
- Matsu**yuki Atsu**mu = Yukiatsu
- **Tsuru**mi Chiri**ko** = Tsuruko
- Hisakawa Tetsudou = Poppo??

Does it have something to do with his name in Japanese characters?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a bit of searching on the Japanese internet, I found an explanation that makes so much sense that it almost *must* be right. That said, I haven't found official material to back this up,<sup>1</sup> so this may yet be incorrect.

Here's the deal: "Tetsudou", written 鉄道, [means "railway"](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E9%89%84%E9%81%93). "Poppo" (ぽっぽ) is a childish/onomatopoetic word for a steam train (see e.g. [the zokugo-dict entry](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/srch/jn/%E6%B1%BD%E8%BB%8A/m0u/), usage 3 [in Japanese]). So I suppose what would have happened is that the kids would've gone along some sort of chain of word associations and ended up deciding to call the guy "Poppo" because that's related to "Tetsudou".

---

<sup>1</sup> Then again, there may not even *be* any official material to support this explanation - I think this joke/whatever would be very transparent to people brought up in Japan and so this connection would probably go without saying.

Answer (score 2):

Poppo is the Japanese equivalent of the English "Choo-choo" both which are onomatopoetic words for a steam locomotive, derived from the sound it makes. It is pronounced Poe-poe, not Pop-oh. I know this because I have visited a railway and museum for tourists in Japan named "Poppo Town".